# how to prevent stop webrtc on chrome extension when pop.html (pop.js) closed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, progressive-web-apps

i wrote a chrome extension for live chat connection. connecting clients by webrtc and start chatting.
but if any of client close chrome extension popup they lose connection and everything restart from beginning,

and I'm beginner and using manifest v3.
how to keep connection open like vpn extensions ?

Comment: The popup is a separate window, which only runs when shown. You can use the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) for webrtc and communicate via BroadcastChannel or chrome.runtime messaging.